# Can I pass multiple rows from a stored procedure query into another query?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by

In my previous question I asked about storing the result of a query in a variable... now I realize the query can return multiple rows.

I currently have this:

```
SELECT @UserId = UserId FROM aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = @username
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM some_table WHERE UserId IN ( *the ID list* )
DELETE FROM some_table_2 WHERE UserId IN ( *the ID list* )
```

My first instinct is to use "GROUP_CONCAT" but apparently that's a MySQL-only feature. There are some ways to make equivalent functionality, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to structure the queries?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Why the removal of the `group-concat` tag? Not that it matters... but what was the point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles 
WHERE UserId IN ( 
    SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Users 
    WHERE UserName = @username  
)
```

Comment: I want to execute multiple queries using the same IDs, though. Using that subquery for everyone is gonna get a bit messy.

Comment: From a bit of research it looks like the results would be cached if I use the same query multiple times. Still makes my code look a little messy but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

this should do it ..

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles 
WHERE 
  UserId IN ( 
             SELECT 
               UserId 
             FROM 
               aspnet_Users 
             WHERE 
               UserName = @username
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from st
    from some_table st
        inner join aspnet_Users au
            on st.UserId = au.UserId
    where /* add additional criteria here to produce "* the ID list *" */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid to repeat subquery you can put its result into a temp table or a table variable. For instance:

```
/*declare and fill a table variable containing all user ids you need to manipulate*/
declare @t table(userid int)
insert into @t(userid) select UserId from aspnet_Users where UserName=@username

/*delete from some table by using the temp variable*/
delete from st 
from some_table st 
    inner join @t t 
        on st.userid = t.userid 
/*repeat this for some other table*/
delete from st 
from some_other_table st 
    inner join @t t 
        on st.userid = t.userid
```

If you want to avoid multiple delete statements and if presence of user ids in some_other_table doesn't make sense if this doesn't exist in the some_table then you can create trigger on some_table:

```
create trigger x on some_table for delete
    as
    begin
     delete from some_other_table 
     where userid in (select userid from deleted)
  end
```